# Web development using Play! framework

Tags: java, web, playframework-2.0

I started learning and developing with Play! framework. I love this framework, it's simple and easy to learn. Yet, I think there's one disadvantage when comparing Play! (and JAVA) to other frameworks using a dynamic language (like Python, Ruby..)

For every change (front-end or back-end) I have to wait for the classes to be compiled, even if it's just a simple HTML adjustment.

I want to know if there's a smart way to "overcome" this.
I can think of one which is styling your frontend independently from the project and only then attach it.

Still, Is there any other thing that can be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make any additional efforts - Play has *hot-compile* feature built-in.

Just while development use `play ~run` command to start the application and ... work. It causes that changes are compiled as soon as possible (after detecting changes in file(s)).

Of course if you changing lot o files without saving and then you'll save all of them at once the compilation will take several seconds, but when saving often small changes (ie. consider using IDE with auto-save function) Play compiles them *almost* in the fly.

Comment: yeah, it's a matter of couple of seconds, but it's not as immediate as dynamic languages are. I guess the grass is always greener...

Comment: Yes Java is compiled... that's it... anyway finally in production stage you don't need to compile anything anymore. Take as an example some PHP frames - PHP is dynamic too, but because of performance they building some caches... believe me that even in PHP such _rebuild_ can eat several minutes in large projects :)

Answer (score 1):

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

what you asked for is JRebel.

> Every time a developer tests a code change it takes minutes to build and deploy the application. JRebel keeps the app server running at all times, so testing is instantaneous and interactive.

as they described themselves

Comment: Play 2.x has this possibility without requirement to use any 3-rd part soft.